# Does stackoverflow have an equivalent subdomain under stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, subdomains

I know that most stackexchange site urls are subdomains under stackexchange.com, such as [android.se](http://android.stackexchange.com) and [unix.se](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Do the legacy sites (namely Stack Overflow, Super User and Server Fault) and others (e.g. http://askubuntu.com) also have a subdomain under stackexchange that would forward to their site?

If not, should they? I could see it being useful to have the option of all sites under one domain, and redirecting to or from the original unique domains.

Comment: If you don't mind expanding on your post - what problem would this solve? Why is this an issue? Or rather - how would this be useful?

Comment: Firstly it just seems a bit inconsistent. Do any new stackexchange sites get their own domain, or do they always get put as a subdomain (and the original sites only keep their domains because they are grandfathered out of that policy)? Also, perhaps new users would see something like serverfault.com and wonder if it is a clone (and thus not as reputable) or actually part of the stackexchange network.

Comment: At any rate, it was just a thought that popped in my head, and I figured I'd ask on meta to see what others thought.

Comment: Are you aware of the history of the different sites? With that context, it makes perfect sense. Consider that changing the [so] domain now would be foolish.

Comment: [Just try it](http://stackoverflow.stackexchange.com). (well, "Site not found")

Comment: @Oded I think he means adding it, not replacing the existing domain. (and http://stackoverflow.stackexchange.com/ would redirect to http://stackoverflow.com same way http://meta.stackexchange.com already redirect here)

Comment: I just found a blog post on stackoverflow that explains a bit about choosing domain names for the .se sites. It's from 2010, but it still pertains to this question. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/

Comment: Such a feature would most likely make programing apps and other things for [se] much easier!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, currently the legacy sites have no sub domain under https://stackexchange.com/: (all lead to "Site not found page)

1. http://stackoverflow.stackexchange.com/
2. http://serverfault.stackexchange.com/
3. http://superuser.stackexchange.com/

Other sites **do** have sub domains, e.g.

1. http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com redirects to https://askubuntu.com/
2. http://meta.stackexchange.com is this very site

Should we add sub domains for the legacy sites? I don't think so. Those sites predate Stack Exchange network and can't see any real benefit from having such sub domain.

Comment: I don't know how significant it is, but there'd be a _little_ benefit if someone wanted to map, e.g., site names to subdomains so that they could automatically generate `http://$SUBDOMAINS[SITE-ID].stackexchange.com`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor what do you mean "automatically generate"? What for?

Comment: I don't have a particular use case in mind. Maybe someone developing applications would find it useful. I'm just speaking from the perspective of a programmer and semantic webby/linked data person.  Canonical identifiers that follow a predictable pattern can be handy. It seemed like a point in contrast to "Those sites predate Stack Exchange network and can't see any real benefit from having such sub domain." This seems like a potentially "real benefit from having such sub domain[s]." It's not necessarily a _big_ benefit. The early ones are the sort of special cases we'd refactor in other code.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I think I get your point but yeah, doesn't sound significant enough.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor. If you want such a list, use the API: http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=999&filter=default&run=true.